# How do I control the width of a canvas page for a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a simple Facebook application and for the canvas page I'm using an iFrame. I need to make the width of the iframe wider to fit my site.  Is there a way to control this and what would I need to do to support that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two supported canvas page sizes (760px and 646px). These can be set on the developer settings for your application.

You can not make your canvas page wider, however you could make it narrower by making your application and FBML application and then putting your content inside of an fb:iframe tag with a reduced width.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fb developer's wiki entry on [canvas](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Canvas). They set the width it in the canvas tag.
e.g. `<canvas id="Canvas1" width=200 height=270></canvas>`

fb mark up for [iFrame](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:iframe)